# Pandas extract the highest degree of qualification basis importance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem where I need to select the highest degree for a particular candidate basis the different degrees that they have completed. To select the highest degree the following order should follow :

**PHD>MBA>Masters>Bachelors>Others**

PHD has the highest priority and Others the lowest

The dataframe looks like the following :

```
ID  Degree
1   Bachelors
1   Masters
1   PHD
2   Bachelors
2   Others
3   PHD
3   Masters
```

The output should like this :

```
ID Degree
1  PHD
2  Bachelors
3  PHD
```

I have no idea how to even start with this requirement hence not able to add any code snippet here.

Comment: would you please clarify your sorting strategy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we do `Categorical`, then `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.Degree = pd.Categorical(df.Degree, ordered=True,
                   categories='PHD>MBA>Masters>Bachelors>Others'.split('>')[::-1])
Yourdf=df.sort_values('Degree').drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')
   ID     Degree
3   2  Bachelors
2   1        PHD
5   3        PHD
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary to sort your items :

```
order_dict = {'PHD' : 0, 'MBA' : 1, 'Masters' : 2,'Bachelors':3, 'Others' : 4}


df.assign(key=df["Degree"].map(order_dict)).sort_values(["ID", "key"]).drop(
    "key", axis=1
)
```

---

```
print(df)
   ID     Degree
2  1   PHD      
1  1   Masters  
0  1   Bachelors
3  2   Bachelors
4  2   Others   
5  3   PHD      
6  3   Masters
```

if you want unique then just add `drop_duplicates` with subset on ID:

```
print(df.assign(key=df["Degree"].map(order_dict)).sort_values(["ID", "key"]).drop(
    "key", axis=1
).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='first'))
```

---

```
  ID     Degree
2  1   PHD      
3  2   Bachelors
5  3   PHD
```

Comment: In this case you should add `df.groupby("ID").first()` in order to get the output the OP is asking for

Comment: @rpanai drop duplicates a little better here :) added that thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

'Try this: But not sure this is the answer you expected'

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'Degree':['Bachelors','Masters','PHD','Bachelors','Others','PHD','Masters']})

df3

df3['Degree'].value_counts()

def priority(val):  
        if val == 'PHD':  
                return 1  
        elif val == 'Bachelors':  
               return 2  
        else:  
               return 0  

df3[df3['Degree'].apply(lambda x: priority(x)) >0]['Degree'].tail(3)
```